# Can't store value of $? to variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh, wget

I have the following code:

```
errorlevel=-1

{ wget "$1" -O "$2" 2>&1; errorlevel=$?; } |\
sed -u 's/^[a-zA-Z\-].*//; s/.* \{1,2\}\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)%.*/\1\n#Downloading... \1%/; s/^20[0-9][0-9].*/#Done./' | \
dlg --progress --percentage=0 --title=Download dialog --text=Starting... --auto-close --auto-kill --button=gtk-cancel
```

However, regardless of whatever `wget` returns, I always get `-1` in `$errorlevel`. Seems like `$errorlevel` isn't modified at all by that statement.

Where am I doing this wrong and how do I fix this?

(`PIPESTATUS` or `set -o pipefail` etc. are not usable in this case, otherwise I won't be able to tell if the user has cancelled the operation or not (`dlg` invokes a GUI).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not like the `PIPESTATUS` solution of @devnull (which I would understand; after all it binds you closely to the `bash` and other shells which support that feature), you maybe can do it like this:

```
{
  wget "$1" -O "$2" 2>&1
  errorlevel=$?
  echo "Now I'm using the variable errorlevel:" 1>&2  # redirect to avoid piping this into sed below
  case $errorlevel in
    143) # segfault?
      echo "Whoa!" 1>&2
      ;;
    # ...
  esac
} | sed -u 's/^[a-zA-Z\-].*//; s/.* \{1,2\}\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)%.*/\1\n#Downloading... \1%/; s/^20[0-9][0-9].*/#Done./' | \
dlg --progress --percentage=0 --title=Download dialog --text=Starting... --auto-close --auto-kill --button=gtk-cancel
```

You also can consider to use a fifo to split the piping into two commands:

```
mkfifo /tmp/ff
cat /tmp/ff/ | sed ... | dlg ... &
wget ... > /tmp/ff
errorlevel=$?
rm /tmp/ff
```

This way you might have trouble capturing the output of the `sed ... | dlg ...` pipe, but maybe that is not interesting for you.

And of course you can step away from piping and capture the `wget` output first, and then start the `sed` and `dlg` if and only if `wget` was successful:

```
wgetOutput=$(wget ...)
errorlevel=$?
case $errorlevel in
  0)
    echo "$wgetOutput" | sed ... | dlg ...
    ;;
  # add other cases here for handle errors of wget.
esac
```

But this can only work for limited amounts of output from `wget`.  It won't work for streams of course.

Answer (score 3):

> I always get `-1` in `$errorlevel`.

That's because you are setting the variable in a subshell.

The changes made to the variable are lost upon exiting the subshell.

You might want to look at `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`.

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` or `set -o pipefail` etc. are not usable in this case, otherwise I won't be able to tell if the user has cancelled the operation or not (`dlg` invokes a GUI).

Comment: @user2064000 Why? You want the returncode of `wget` and `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` gives you exactly that. `false | true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[*]}"` => `1 0`, `true | false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[*]}"` => `0 1`.